# Relative path Issue - TypeScript compiler behaving differently on Windows vs Linux

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, angular, linux-mint, typescript1.7

I have used `relative Paths` to import modules created in my `Angular2` and `TypeScript` application.

**Example**  ([Source Code](https://github.com/akankshagaur/cleanshave))

```
import {Http} from 'angular2/http';
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Person} from '../core/Person';
```

This compiles fine on windows (tsc v1.7.5) but is not able to load on Linux.

> **Questions:**
>
> 1. Why is this behaving so on linux?
> 2. Is there a standard way to declare path of modules in typescript?

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
     "wwwroot/lib"
  ]
}
```

**Error on Ubuntu 14.04**

> wwwroot/app/people/people.service.ts(3,22): error TS2307: Cannot find module '../core/Person'.
>   wwwroot/app/routes.config.ts(1,22): error TS2307: Cannot find module './home/Home'.
>   wwwroot/app/routes.config.ts(2,23): error TS2307: Cannot find module './about/About'.
>   wwwroot/app/routes.config.ts(3,24): error TS2307: Cannot find module './people/People'.
>   wwwroot/app/routes.config.ts(4,30): error TS2307: Cannot find module './people/PersonDetail'.

As you can see from sourcecode on github, Person.ts contains the class person located in wwwroot\app\core\Person.ts

Please help me resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you definitely using the same version of typescript (1.7.5) on Ubuntu? I see your `package.json` has `"typescript": "^1.6.2"`

Comment: yes, i installed tsc globally. i tried running after correcting the version in package.json, still getting d same error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the problem.

> Windows ignores case in directory & file names whereas linux does not.

After keeping all folder and file names in small case and replicating the same in imports. It compiled successfully.

Comment: This was the solution to my issue. The same goes for OSX. OSX does not care about case when importing, but Ubuntu was for me. Matching the case fixed it.

Comment: This worked for me. changing the file imports to lower case worked for ng serve.